# Time Travel on my MBA

Tags: macos

I was alerted about my system time been wrong by a chrome tab. Why and how did my system clock go backwards showing almost 14 months behind and all Chrome tabs are showing the wrong Date/Time

[image: clock]

I keep it updated via apple server

[image]

Restart fixed it but still do not know what happened.

MBA 2017 with Monetary

Comment: Are you saying that macOS had the correct time before the reboot and chrome did not?

Comment: No, the system time was also wrong

Comment: Curious if `last reboot` and using the console app let you roll back the logs to find out how long ago this started? Sometimes with large time offsets, the log rolling behavior lets you easily see which of the saved logs the time jumps

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you use a VPN of some kind?

Comment: @Allan no, do not have/use VPN

Comment: @bmike it must have happened overnight, since it was fine the day before, thus I did not initiate reboot

Comment: I’ve been able to capture down to the second when the logs shift time in the past. Hopefully something makes sense on the reset for you. Rogue NTP server perhaps?

Comment: Just do not know where to look, maybe is it the `453 com.apple.WebKit.WebContent gettimeofday`

Answer (score -1):

Browsing through the Internet it seems like Chrome has it's own idea of what time it is, and this can get corrupted. If it persists across restarts, try telling chrome to dump its cache.